# Excel Pricing Model with value bands

Tags: excel

I am working on developing a pricing model in Excel and am running into an error when trying to use an array formula for the below.

[Pricing Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iyWq.png)

```
|           |             |        |        |      |      |      |      Cycle      
|-----------|-------------|--------|--------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| Region    | Region Code | Low    | High   | A    | X    | P    | 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    |
| NorthEast | 1           | 10000  | 25000  | -61% | N/A  | 38%  | TBD  |      |      |      |
| NorthEast | 1           | 25000  | 50000  | -32% | N/A  | -2%  | -2%  | -2%  | -2%  | -2%  |
| NorthEast | 1           | 50000  | 75000  | -21% | -50% | -34% | -34% | -34% | -34% | -34% |
| NorthEast | 1           | 75000  | 100000 | -38% | -26% | -19% | -19% | -19% | -19% | -19% |
| NorthEast | 1           | 100000 | 125000 | -27% | -45% | -21% | -21% | -21% | -21% | -21% |
```

The variables i am searching for in the formula are 
Region 1
Cycle 2
value 35000

I need the formula to look for the Region Code, the value between the Low and High figures, and then finally which cycle the value is in to return the % in the table on the right side under the Cycle Columns.

So far I have tried an Index Match Array to search for these variables:

```
=INDEX(I12:L15, MATCH(1,(C:C=P19)*(10:10=Q19)*((D:D>=R19)/(E:E<=R19)),0))
```

P19= 1 (region code), Q19=2, R19= 35000 . Column C in this case is the Region Code Column of the table, Column D is the Low Value, Column E is the High value, and Row 10 is where the Cycles are located.

Excel is running out of resources when trying to calculate this. I'm sure there is a better way to do this calculation, perhaps with multiple Vlookup/Hlookup/Lookups together.

I could also set up the table in a different manner I suppose, but I felt this was the best way to present the data.

Comment: my apologies, first time posting on here, wasn't sure of exact protocol. "Excel has run out of resources"

Comment: Where does value 35000 come from? Can you talk through an example case with expected output? And bear in mind we can't see row numbers of columns to guide us, which would really help, so referring to P19 and R19 etc has no context and so I have no idea what is in those columns.

Comment: thank you for the table generator, trying to get this formatted correctly but everything is misaligned, i will continue working on this. the value is a generic one to test this out.  sure thing, for this case in particular, the value of 35000 is in region 1 and in it's 2nd cycle, since the value falls between 25,000 and 50,000, the expected result would be -2%.

Comment: understood, P19= 1 (this is the Region Code), and R19 =2 (this is the Cycle the asset is in). Column C in this case is the Region Code Column of the table, Column D is the Low Value, Column E is the High value, and Row 10 is where the Cycles are located. i will try to get these in the table to make things easier to read, again my apologies for not presenting this in the easiest manner.

Comment: sure that would be great. also, R19= 35000, the value.

Comment: please verify you are happy with edits

Comment: How is R19 both 2 and 35000?

Comment: the edits look great, thank you! wow my brain is not operating well today... P19= 1, Q19=2, R19= 35000

Answer (score 1):

Good question for first post IMHO.

I think the formula below is on the right lines and shows how you can do it more efficiently using INDEX/MATCH, but lacks error handing at present (i.e. value less than 10000 would give #N/A, greater than 125000 would give the same answer as 125000).

```
=INDEX($I:$L,MATCH(R2,INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(P2,$C:$C,0)):INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(P2,$C:$C)))+MATCH(P2,$C:$C,0)-1,MATCH(Q2,$I$1:$L$1,0))
```

[image]

EDIT

Here is a revised formula with error handling

```
=IFERROR(IF($R2>INDEX(E:E,MATCH($P2,$C:$C)),"",INDEX($I:$L,MATCH($R2,INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($P2,$C:$C,0)):INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($P2,$C:$C)))+MATCH($P2,$C:$C,0)-1,MATCH($Q2,$I$1:$L$1,0))),"")
```

Comment: You never cease to amaze me!

Comment: these are both excellent guys, thank you so much. going to test them out now!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a UDF which you can call from in the sheet. The code would go in a standard module. Some more error checking is probably needed.

If value not found `-999999`   is returned which is then formatted as a percentage in the sheet.

**In sheet use:**

[image: Data]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetPercentage(ByVal Region As Long, ByVal Cycle As Long, ByVal Amount As Double) As Double

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")       'change as appropriate

    Dim lookupSource()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    If Cycle < 1 Or Cycle > 4 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid cycle chosen"
        GetPercentage = -999999                  'chose your not found return value
        Exit Function
    End If

    With wsSource
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Assuming data starts in C2
    lookupSource = wsSource.Range("C2:N" & lastRow).Value2 'change as appropriate

    Dim requiredColumn As Long

    requiredColumn = Application.Match(Cycle, wsSource.Range("C2:N2"), 0)

    Dim currentRow As Long

    For currentRow = 2 To UBound(lookupSource, 1)

        If lookupSource(currentRow, 2) = Region And lookupSource(currentRow, 3) <= Amount And lookupSource(currentRow, 4) >= Amount Then

            GetPercentage = lookupSource(currentRow, requiredColumn)
            Exit Function
        Else
            GetPercentage = -999999
        End If

    Next currentRow

End Function
```

Comment: Tom, the index match formula you posted works brilliantly for this! thank you so much! QHarr, I will give the UDF a try a little later today but i applaud you both for your efforts, i've learned something new today!